# Sum of a number of shifted exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: distributions, random-variable, density-function, sum

I know that the sum of $k$ independent exponentially distributed random variables each with density function:
$$\displaystyle \lambda\,{{\rm e}^{-\lambda\,x}}$$
has an Erlang distribution:
$$\displaystyle {\frac {{\lambda}^{k}{x}^{k-1}{{\rm e}^{-\lambda\,x}}}{ \left( k-1 \right) !}} $$
What would the sum density function look like for a sum of k independent exponentially distributed random variables, each with a density function:
$$\displaystyle \lambda\,{{\rm e}^{-\lambda\,(x-a)}},$$
where $a$ is a shift parameter.

Comment: I am convinced that a small amount of thinking can lead you to the answer.

Comment: Perhaps ask yourself, what is the distribution of $X-a$ here?